# How can I trigger a method after a variable in a dependency is updated?

Tags: swift, asynchronous

How can I trigger a method after a variable in a dependency is updated in Swift?

My groupViewModel initializes a user repository that gets the list of users in the group, using the following flow:

```
init(groupRepository: GroupStoreType, groupUserRepository: GroupUserStoreType, group accountabilityGroup: AccountabilityGroup) {
    self.groupRepository = groupRepository
    self.groupUserRepository = groupUserRepository
    self.group = accountabilityGroup
    
    // Setting this in the repository triggers the loadUsers 
    // method in the repository
    self.groupUserRepository.groupId = self.group.id
    
    // I want to run a method that does a sanity check on all the users
    // that verifies their data matches the group after the repository completes
    // it's method, but before I run loadActiveMembers() and loadPendingMembers() below.

    loadActiveMembers()
    loadPendingMembers()
}
```

Then in my user repository, setting the groupId to something other than nil will trigger the function that loads users matching that group:

```
var groupId: String? {
    didSet {
        if groupId != nil && groupId != oldValue {
            self.loadByGroupId()
        }
    }
}
```

That loading function will either listen to a cloud Firestore collection or subscribe to a static list of users (for my mocked version for unit testing).

I want to run a `verifyUsersMatchGroup` method in the ViewModel after the repository loads the users, but before the ViewModel runs the `loadActiveMembers` and `loadPendingMembers` methods. Any ideas on good ways to accomplish this?

I thought about having a `usersLoaded` Bool var in the repository, and having that published to a similar variable in the ViewModel, then triggering my method in the didSet of that, but I'm wondering if there are simpler ways to accomplish this. (This app is currently not yet set for iOS 15.)

Comment: It sounds to me like a Combine pipeline would be simplest. That is how to line up asynchronous calls most cleanly before iOS 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned a combine pipeline would be a perfect use case for this I've assumed you would want to return a `Bool` - If you don't need to return specific data type back from `verifyUsersMatchGroup` you could replace `Bool` with `Void` and pass `()` on the promise success. Then when you sink the you can remove the if. You could do this all on the viewModel too. Don't forget to import Combine ;)

```
func verifyUsersMatchGroup() -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    Future { promise in
        // Put the internal workings of the method here once you 
        // Don't forget to call promise(.success(boolValue))
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Then use the `verifyUsersMatchGroup` function like so:

```
var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

verifyUsersMatchGroup()
    .sink {
        if $0 {
            // Users match 
        } else {
            // Users don't match
        }
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)
```